# Why did all the guest students take carriages to the Yule Ball?

Tags: plot-explanation, harry-potter, the-goblet-of-fire

In *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*, why did all of the guest students take carriages to the Yule Ball if the Yule Ball takes place at Hogwarts?

Comment: please explain your question in detail

Comment: Were the guests staying at Hogwarts?

Answer (score 11):

Because the guests were not staying exactly in Hogwarts, they were staying in the vessels they arrived in.

Durmstrang in their [ship](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Durmstrang_Ship) and Beauxbatons in their [carriage](https://pottermore.fandom.com/wiki/The_Beauxbatons_Carriage).

They were 'parked' outside of Hogwarts, so the carriages were there to take the students from their vessels to Hogwarts.